# Can't find partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partition-recovery, raid-1

I have a server with two hard disk - in rescue mode because one of the disk failed and had to be replaced -.

I had to hire a data recovery service, few days later they told me that it was ready, but they couldn't open a terminal in order to mount the filesystem. So I opened a SSH terminal and I tried to mount the filesystem.

In rescue mode I can't use fdisk command, is not available. So I tried with lsblk with this result:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0 190.9M  1 loop
sda     8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
sdb     8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
```

Then I tried to list partitions with parted -l with this result:

```
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA Hitachi HDT72502 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA Hitachi HDT72502 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Then I tried to list partitions with sgdisk -l /dev/sda with this result:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.6
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table entries is 257317316 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table entries is 164259508 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sda: 488397168 sectors, 232.9 GiB
Model: Hitachi HDT72502
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes Disk identifier (GUID): 6252014C-6128-5CBC-64B3-43B93D2746D4
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33 First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 488397134 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries Total free space is 488397101 sectors (232.9 GiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

And then I tried to list with second disk; sgdisk -l /dev/sdb with this result:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.6
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sdb: 488397168 sectors, 232.9 GiB
Model: Hitachi HDT72502
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes Disk identifier (GUID): CBA264B1-5BCC-54F3-BF89-23B5C2B3733B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33 First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 488397134 Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries Total free space is 488397101 sectors (232.9 GiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Then I checked if sda disk contained data with dd if=/dev/sda|hexdump -C and yes. But sdb disk was empty:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb|hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
```

Then I tried to get RAID info with mdadm --query /dev/sda with this result:

```
/dev/sda: is not an md array
```

Some additional information: I can only connect with SSH terminal in remote and only can use these commands:

```
agetty            devlink          e2undo       fsck.reiserfs  ip           lvconvert    lvscan       mkfs.msdos         pvchange         route              sysctl           vgextend
badblocks         dhcpcd           ethtool      fsck.vfat      ipmaddr      lvcreate     mdadm        mkfs.reiserfs      pvck             rtacct             tc               vgimport
blkdeactivate     dmeventd         fatlabel     fsck.xfs       iptunnel     lvdisplay    mdmon        mkfs.vfat          pvcreate         rtmon              telinit          vgimportclone
blkdiscard        dmraid           findfs       fsfreeze       isosize      lvextend     mii-tool     mkfs.xfs           pvdisplay        runlevel           tipc             vgmerge
blkid             dmraid-activate  fixparts     fstab-decode   jfs_debugfs  lvm          mkdosfs      mkhomedir_helper   pvmove           runuser            tune2fs          vgmknodes
blkzone           dmsetup          fsadm        fstrim         jfs_fsck     lvmconfig    mke2fs       mkreiserfs         pvremove         setcap             tunefs.reiserfs  vgreduce
blockdev          dmstats          fsck         gdisk          jfs_fscklog  lvmdiskscan  mkfs         mkswap             pvresize         sgdisk             unix_chkpwd      vgremove
bridge            dosfsck          fsck.btrfs   getcap         jfs_logdump  lvmdump      mkfs.bfs     nameif             pvs              shadowconfig       unix_update      vgrename
capsh             dosfslabel       fsck.cramfs  getpcaps       jfs_mkfs     lvmpolld     mkfs.btrfs   parted             pvscan           shutdown           vgcfgbackup      vgs
cgdisk            dumpe2fs         fsck.ext2    getty          jfs_tune     lvmsadc      mkfs.cramfs  partprobe          rarp             slattach           vgcfgrestore     vgscan
chcpu             e2fsck           fsck.ext3    halt           killall5     lvmsar       mkfs.ext2    pivot_root         raw              start-stop-daemon  vgchange         vgsplit
coldreboot        e2image          fsck.ext4    hdparm         kpartx       lvreduce     mkfs.ext3    plipconfig         reboot           sulogin            vgck             wipefs
ctrlaltdel        e2label          fsck.fat     hwclock        ldconfig     lvremove     mkfs.ext4    pm-hibernate       reiserfsck       swaplabel          vgconvert        xfs_repair
debugfs           e2mmpstatus      fsck.jfs     ifconfig       logsave      lvrename     mkfs.fat     pm-suspend         reiserfstune     swapoff            vgcreate         zramctl
debugfs.reiserfs  e2scrub          fsck.minix   init           losetup      lvresize     mkfs.jfs     pm-suspend-hybrid  resize2fs        swapon             vgdisplay
debugreiserfs     e2scrub_all      fsck.msdos   installkernel  lvchange     lvs          mkfs.minix   poweroff           resize_reiserfs  switch_root        vgexport
```

How can I recover the partitions?. I think it's impossible, but I keep trying because they told me that the data could still be recovered.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A data recovery service that didn't give you files? Just a drive and a 'good luck with it'? - Weird. The *entire* drive is empty/zeros?

Comment: You should STOP doing stuff to the original drives. First clone then (ddrescue).

Comment: Yes. :( They sent me technical documentation about how view the partitions and after writing and sending them screenshots of the shell console they told me that they couldn't do more.

Comment: Thanks Joep, just tried to list the partitions with original drives. I thought of cloning sda data in sdb empty disk with something like dd if=/dev/sda|pv|dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M  but i'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: Hope you did not pay too much for the recovery service; they did not do a sufficient job. My advice would be: get a SATA-USB convertor and a big USB disk (bigger than `sda`). Then get a laptop with Linux. Clone the sda onto the USB disk.  Then run `testdisk` on it (you may need to install it and read some tutorials about it)

Comment: Thanks Ljm. I can only connect in rescue mode with my server with SSH terminal, can't use a USB disk. I thought of cloning sda data in sdb empty disk with something like dd if=/dev/sda|pv|dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M and then work with sda in order to be able to reboot the server in normal mode and yes, install testdisk. But I don't know if is a good idea.

Comment: You're really doing the work the lab should have done. For a more hand-holding approach I suggest you post your issue here: https://www.reddit.com/r/datarecovery/

Comment: It looks like the data recovery firm did - at best - nothing, and at worst deleted your data.  If your disk is made up of only 0's "on a clear disk you can seek forever".   You might wat to run photorec over the disk just to see if there is anything there to even try and recover.  If that works, clone the disk and play with testdisk to see if it can find partitions.

Comment: Thanks Joep, I will try in reddit.com too.

Comment: Thanks davidgo, I can't use a USB disk, I think to try cloning sda disk in sdb empty disk and then work with sda in order to be able to boot the server in normal mode, but I'm not sure if cloning to sdb and create partitions in sda is a good idea.